# Getting local var from caller function via EBP

Tags: c, assembly, x86, stack

I'm trying to get a local variable defined in the caller from the callee via EBP. It should be possible, but if it's not, please explain why.

This is the code I have right now:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void TEST(int a, int b, int c){
  int answer;
  printf("a: %d | b: %d | c: %d\n", a, b, c);

  __asm__ __volatile__(
    ".intel_syntax;"
    "mov %0, dword ptr ds:[ebp + 20];"        <-- EBP+20 == d == 42
    ".att_syntax;"
    : "=r" (answer)
    :
    :
  );

  printf("Answer: %d\n", answer);
}

int main(void){
  int a = 13;
  int b = 14;
  int c = 15;
  int d = 42;
  TEST(a, b, c);
}
```

By the time `TEST` gets called I expect the stack to look the following way:

```
|+20|  | 13     <-- d
|+16|  | 14     <-- c
|+12|  | 15     <-- b
|+ 8|  | 42     <-- a
|+ 4|  | return address
|  0|  | EBP
|- 4|  | local var answer
|- 8|  | ...
```

If I try to compile the following code I get:

```
test.c: Assembler messages:
test.c:7: Error: segment register name expected
```

Where is the error?

Comment: @qwr Care to elaborate a little bit this? Why shouldn't I push to stack before calling? Also, does your answer mean I can't achieve what I'm trying? If so, why?

Comment: @qwr Calling conventions explicitly say arguments should be pushed on the stack. What should I read about that? Writing in Intel syntax instead of AT&T is a personal choise and I can't see how that will affect in any way the result.

Comment: d is no arg, so it is not pushed; args are *pushed* in inverse order, so change your stack diagram to ret - a- b - c.

Comment: @gnometorule ```d``` is not an arg, but I'd expect it to be on the stack anyways. Isn't that correct?

Comment: @gnometorule Ah, I see what you mean. Yes, It should be +20 instead of +8, but that doesn't fix my error (which happens at compile time, not at run time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
move mem2,mem1
```

is not allowed.But this will be handled  by gcc even on intel syntax. my assumtion was incorrect. `Gcc` will generate correct code for both `intel` and `at&t` syntax.

```
 "movl  mem1,%0"
        : "=r" (mem2)
```

Gcc will generate valid code for us:

```
mov    mem1,%eax
 mov    %eax,mem2
```

### **Error: segment register name expected**:

gcc cant get segment register name.But  there is segment `ds` register.Plus it should be ok even without mentioning segment register.**Actual problem was just prefix problem**

**Should be done:**
to solve this we have to use `nonprefix`
or  put prefixes `%`

### The same Example :

Its on x64 machine. you should change rbp->ebp. and also 0x10 can be changed

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
 #include <stdint.h>
void TEST(int a, int b, int c) {
    int answer;

    int x = 16;


  __asm__ __volatile__(  
            ".intel_syntax noprefix ;"
            "mov %0, dword ptr   ds:[rbp + %1+0];"
  ".att_syntax;"
            : "=r" (answer) 
            : "r"((uintptr_t)x) /* x is input operand */
             );  
      printf("Answer: %d\n", answer);
    __asm__ __volatile__(  
   " movl    0(%%rbp,%1,1),%0"
            : "=r" (answer) 
            : "r"((uintptr_t)x) /* x is input operand */
             );  
      printf("Answer: %d\n", answer);
    __asm__ __volatile__(
            "movl  0x10(%%rbp),%0"
            : "=r" (answer)
            );
    printf("Answer: %d\n", answer);
    __asm__ __volatile__(
            ".intel_syntax;"
            "mov %0, dword ptr  [%%rbp + 0x10];"
            ".att_syntax;"
            : "=r" (answer)
            );
    printf("Answer: %d\n", answer);

    //the same as you wrote, just I added noprefix
    __asm__ __volatile__(
            ".intel_syntax noprefix ;"
            "mov %0, dword ptr   ds:[rbp + 0x10];"
            ".att_syntax;"
            : "=r" (answer)
            );
    printf("Answer: %d\n", answer);
    //this lines just to test if we refer the same address as address of d
    void *addressd;
    __asm__ __volatile__(
            "lea  0x10(%%rbp),%0"
            : "=r" (addressd)
            );
    printf("TEST: address of d %p\n", addressd);
}

int main(void) {
    int a = 13;
    int b = 14;
    int c = 15;
    int d = 42;
    TEST(a, b, c);
    printf("address of d %p", &d);
}
```

Comment: Indeed, your code works :) But I'd really like to understand how to make it with Intel syntax. ```__asm__ __volatile__(".intel_syntax; mov eax, [ebp + 20]; mov %0, eax; .att_syntax;" : "=r" (answer) : : );``` Is that correct?

Comment: Oh, I got it :)   ```__asm__ __volatile__(".intel_syntax; mov %%eax, [%%rbp + 16]; mov %0, %%eax; .att_syntax;" : "=r" (answer) : : );```
Thank you for the help!

Comment: @alexandernst gcc handle mov mem,mem writings even on intel syntax converting it to valid assembly.Actually, problem was with prefixes(you just needed noprefix keyword).corrected my answer and revised gcc inline assembly )). btw  you too figured out that by yourself )).

Comment: Two more questions. First one: How can I pass the ```0x10``` as input variable of the inline asm? And second question: Why ```d``` is at ```rbp+ 0x10```. Should that be ```rbp+0x8```?

Comment: @alexandernst using $ prefix. cause I am on 64bit . so instead of 4+4 it will be 8+8=16 or 0x10 in hex

Comment: @alexandernst for any non constant  inputs you will do like you did with adding output : section. So first ":" will be outputs , second ":" we will give inputs and after third ":" one clobber list

Comment: @alexandernst I found good gcc inline assembly tutorial. check http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html

Comment: ```"mov %0, [rbp + %1];"``` won't parse the ```%1``` as input value but instead will try to use ```eax``` for some odd reason. Can you check if it works for you?

Comment: probably that value you pass 32bit

Comment: %1 is an unsigned char x_offset = 0x8 (for x86).

Comment: cast it to (unsigned long long) or better use <stdint.h> and cast with (uintptr_t) . wait i add such codes too

Answer (score 1):

I guess your example is for educational purposes only, so it's ok.

But generally be aware that you cannot rely on the order of variables on the stack.
(You can't even rely on finding them on the stack).

For example if you make `d` an `int d[1] = {42}` several compilers will emit `d,a,b,c` instead of `a,b,c,d`. And if you turn on the optimizer everything can happen (and why would you use inline assembly mixed with unoptimized C code?).

[See examples here.](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22:3,%22filterAsm%22%3a%7B%22labels%22%3atrue,%22directives%22%3atrue,%22commentOnly%22%3atrue,%22intel%22%3atrue%7D,%22compilers%22%3a%5B%7B%22source%22%3a%22int%20TEST%28int%20a,%20int%20b,%20int%20c%29;%5Cn%5Cnint%20foo%28%29%5Cn%7B%5Cn%20%20int%20a%20=%201;%5Cn%20%20int%20b%20=%202;%5Cn%20%20int%20c%20=%203;%5Cn%20%20int%20d%20=%204;%5Cn%20%20return%20d%20+%20TEST%28a,b,c%29;%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cnint%20foo_array%28%29%5Cn%7B%5Cn%20%20int%20a%20=%201;%5Cn%20%20int%20b%20=%202;%5Cn%20%20int%20c%20=%203;%5Cn%20%20int%20d%5B1%5D%20=%20%7B4%7D;%5Cn%20%20return%20d%5B0%5D%20+%20TEST%28a,b,c%29;%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn#pragma%20GCC%20optimize%20%28%5C%22O3%5C%22%29%5Cnint%20foo_opt%28%29%5Cn%7B%5Cn%20%20int%20a%20=%201;%5Cn%20%20int%20b%20=%202;%5Cn%20%20int%20c%20=%203;%5Cn%20%20int%20d%20=%204;%5Cn%20%20return%20d%20+%20TEST%28a,b,c%29;%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%22,%22compiler%22%3a%22/usr/bin/g++-4.8%22,%22options%22%3a%22-m32%20-x%20c%22%7D%5D%7D)

Comment: Long story is really long (please check https://github.com/alexandernst/procmon/commit/1caa144ad31249efbbf8cc45f8b96e9ae823e596 is you really want to know what am I doing), but let's just say I'm guaranteed the stack to be the way I think it is. Anyways, thank you for the tip :)